# newton's interpolation error for non-differentiable function

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I was given this function:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^3  & {\text{if}}\ x>0 \\
0 & {\text{if}}\ x\leq0\ 
\end{cases}
$$

and I was asked to give an upper bound on it's interpolation error expressed only by *h* when $ x\in[-h,h] $ and using the known points
$ f(-x_0)=-h, f(x_1)=0, f(x_2)=h $.

So by newton's interpolation method the interpolation polynomial is:
$$
P_2(x) = f(x_0)+f[x_0,x_1,x_2](x-x_0)(x-x_1)
$$

and the error is given by: 
$$
E(x) = f[x_0,x_1,x_2,x](x-x_0)(x-x_1)(x-x_2)
$$

But i have no idea of what is the way to get an upper bound on $|E(x)|$ in this case because clearly the third derivative doesn't exist here and therefore i cannot use the formula $f[x_0,x_1,x_2,x]=f'''(\xi)/3!$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that the third derivative doesn’t exist? $f’(x) = 3x^2$, $f^2(x)= 6x$, and $f^3(x) =6$

Comment: The third derivative at the point $x=0$ is not defined because of the different behavior of the function from the two sides of this point. Am i missing something?

Comment: Correct, but I replied on your statement that the third derivative didn’t exist. So you have to adjust that sentence a little....